# How to change where taxonomy meta data is being saved in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mariadb

in a wordpress site how to change taxonomy meta data like long description that is beign saved to one cell in wp_options row is core_admin_values and column is option_value. i want to save that text to new table called wp_custom_tax_meta row is the term_id of each taxonomy and column is long_description. if you need inputs please ask

here is some php code i found in the theme maybe it will help :

```
// GET THE CURRENT VALUES
                        $existing_values = get_option("core_admin_values");
                        // MERGE WITH EXISTING VALUES
                        $new_result = array_merge((array)$existing_values, (array)$_POST['admin_values']);
                        // UPDATE DATABASE      
                        update_option( "core_admin_values", $new_result);
```

---

expecting to save new data like this in new tabe instead of one cell in old table because its getting huge

| term_id | taxonomy | description | other meta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | term | text | text |
| 2 | term | text | text |

thanks

Comment: This doesn't sound to me as if this was actual taxonomy term meta data stored the way WP usually does these things, but rather something your theme itself "came up" with. But if you want to modify this, then you would not only need to look at the place where this data gets stored into the database - but it would also need modifications in every place where that data it _read_ afterwards.